# Is it possible to back out of a level without completing it?

Tags: ring-fit-adventure

In Ring Fit Adventure, if I choose a level that I don't want to or cannot complete, can I back out to the level select? I know I can exit to the Switch Menu and close the game, but this is time consuming. Is there a way I'm missing? I've tried all of the JoyCon buttons to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can exit a stage from the pause menu.

- Press <kbd>+</kbd> on the Ring-Con to open the pause menu
- Select “To World Map”
- Confirm by selecting “Back to map”